# Transferring image via mobile peer to peer

Tags: android, ios, mobile, p2p

I have a requirement to transfer images between two devices which do not have access to the internet/cellular data and are not on the same network.

I need this to work across Android and iOS, which rules out wifi-direct (Android) and multi-peer connectivity (iOS).

After lots of research, I've concluded that the p2pkit library is my best bet, however data transfer is limited to just 440 bytes which is nothing for an image.

What I'm about to do is create a process that splits images into chunks and transfers via p2pkit, but wanted to double check if anyone is aware of a better way/alternative libraries for achieving this? (Please don't suggest AllJoyn as I painfully learned devices must be on the same network!)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved the issue, I am not able to get P2P Kit working without Internet.